# How to access pixels of a Bitmap image on Android?

Tags: android, image, pixel

In short I am unable to access all the pixels of a bitmap image.

I have used an intent to fire the native Camera app and returned a Bitmap image to my application activity. The data is definitely a bitmap object and I am able to display, get the height/width etc and access some pixels using getPixel(). However when I use the values of getHeight() and getWidth() I get an array out of bounds error. By trail and error I have found I can only access a reduced number of pixels of the image, for example with one image which returned a height and width value of 420,380, I could also access 200,100. I then do some image processing and used setPixel() on the original image. When I display the image it shows the, say 200,100, processing pixels and the rest normal, therefore the pixels are obviously there and accessible by android but not by me. I have to spoken to other people who have also had this problem with images.

Does anyone know anything more about this, reasons? or a work around?

Many thanks in advance.

It seems that there's no way around this, does anyone think it would be better/possible to access the image directly in memory maybe using the NDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from Albert Pucciani on the Android forums. I now create an `int buffer` and copy the pixels to it, then use `get()` and `put()` to extract the pixels. It's also much quicker to use `get()` and `put()` instead of the `get/setPixel()` from the `Bitmap` class. Need to test now whether this does return all the pixels to the buffer for all images.

After more testing I have discovered this is simply a memory issue as the amount allocated for each process includes all bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to access the pixel at (getWidth(),getHeight()) in any image because like everything else they are 0-indexed. The valid range of pixels is (0 to getWidth()-1, 0 to getHeight()-1), and thus the bottomrightmost pixel is obtained by b.getPixel(b.getWidth()-1, b.getHeight()-1).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yeah I'm aware of 0-indexed, the problem is I cant access well over half of the pixels. Basically I have some nested for loops (int y = 0;y<imageHeight;y++) , to cycle through the image and process the RGB values and do some calculations on these, this works fine for my own images in the res/drawable folder but when the bitmap is from the camera app or on the SD card I can only access what looks like the top left quarter of an image. getWidth/getHeight is giving the real dimensions but the app just crashes when i access a pixel over height/2 or width/2 approx.